# Parsing data returned from imageshack API

Tags: php, xml, imageshack

I am in need of your superior web development insight. I was playing with the Imageshack API, and managed to upload a image using a form from my server to imageshack server, and it returns me a rather confusing data back.

Now my question is, what the hell do I do with that to get what I need. Do I have to parse it? I hate regular expressions (but I will deal with it, if I have to). If I have to parse it, how would I send the entire string to a function? I am a bit confused.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php">



<p><input type="file" name="fileupload"></p>

<p><input type="text" name="tags" value="proba,test"></p>

<p><input type="text" name="key" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></p>

<p><select name="optsize">

        <option value="320x240">Small (320x240)</option>

        <option value="426x320" selected>Medium (426x320)</option>

        <option value="640x480">Big (640x480)</option>

</select></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Go"></p>

</form>
```

The data I get back looks something like this.

http://img574.imageshack.us/img574/3084/18835698.png

I guess my question really is, whenever a user presses a submit button, it gives him that junk, how do I parse it dynamically, and give him a pretty result.

Comment: View the source of the page and add another screen shot, we need to see what format the data is in.

Comment: @RobertPitt looks like it is XML according to the tags they have added to their question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dynamic page that allows you to use the CURL lib or more simply an Ajax function.

For example, after passing all the stuff using PHP's CURL you can get the url form the returned XML page using simpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

From the tags on your question I am going to assume the returned data is XML and recommend you look into the native PHP [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) functions to parse the response.

The PHP manual contains a basic example that should get you going: [Basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be doing this in PHP Runtime.

After you have your xml, here's a small function that can be used to get the info:

```
/**
* parsing XML response for info about uploaded file
*   image_link  - URL address of uploaded image on imageshack server
*   thumb_link  - URL address of thumbnail of uploaded image on imageshack server
*   yfrog_link  - URL address of uploaded image on yfrog server
*   yfrog_thumb - URL address of thumbnail of uploaded image on yfrog server  
*   ad_link     - URL address of imgaeshack page with uploaded image
*   done_page   - URL address of thumbnail of uploaded image on imageshack server
*   width       - width of uploaded image [px]
*   height      - height of uploaded image [px]
*/
function getInfo($xml,$key)
{
    preg_match('/<'.$key.'>(.*)<\/'.$key.'>/', $xml, $value);    
    if (empty($value[0])) {
        return('invalid key');
    }else {
        return(strip_tags($value[0]));
    }
}
```

Source of function: http://www.sourcer.cz/ci-lib/imageshack/

usage would be like so:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?url=http://www.mysite.com/myimage.png');
$image_link = getInfo($xml,'image_link');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys, Here's a question though ....how do I get the the data to parse it . I am guessing I have to use the CodeIgniter Imageshack library for this.

Comment: No, i have extraced a method out of that library for you to use, you don't need CI, i was just referencing someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Thanks I get it now.  I did some further research and, another way might be using curl like so :

Using cURL to sent post to "http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"

```
    $data['key'] = API_KEY;
    $data['public'] = "yes";
    $data['xml'] = "yes";
    $data['fileupload'] = '@'.$dest; 

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
    /*curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);*/
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: @Robert, your method definitely looks easier.

Comment: Ah, okay I get it now ...I have to allow a user to upload the file in my server and then generate the xml from the url ( based on my server). I was hoping to bypass the usage of my server to make things more secure. I can check if the files are ending with .jpg, .png and what not. But that still does not make it secure, does it? may be I can generate $xml with curl. and then use the getinfo() function?

Answer (score 0):

all you need is in this link:

http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/source/browse/RedirectAPI.wiki?repo=wiki

You should put this in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="mysite.com/success.php?var1=%s&var2=%b&var3=%i">; 
<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="error.php">
<input type="hidden" name="optsize" id="optsize" value="200x380"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="optimage" id="optimage" value="1"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="rembar" id="rembar" value="1"/>
```

to get the image url:

```
$img_url="http://img$var1.imageshack.us/img$var1/$var2/$var3";
```

to get the tumbnail:

```
$var3= str_replace (".jpg", ".th.jpg", $var3); 
$var3= str_replace (".gif", ".th.gif", $var3); 
$var3= str_replace (".png", ".th.png", $var3); 
$tumb_url="http://img$var1.imageshack.us/img$var1/$var2/$var3";
```

Comment: Can you provide a little context with your link?